# How to set border-radius to scrollable overflowing grid table?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/hatttfu/pen/ZEmVYwr

I have a table made using Grid Css. The problem is I can't set border-radius to it because of overflow: auto, which I need.

What I have:
[image]

What I'd like to achive (radiuses always on borders of table and stay there while scrolling):
[image]

```css
thead, table, tbody, tr, th, td { 
  display: block 
}

.table__row {
  grid-template-columns: 74px 170px 170px 170px 170px 170px 170px 170px 170px 170px 170px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}


.table {
    display: grid;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.table__head {
    background-color: #EDEFF4;
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: 64px;
}

.table__body {
    display: grid;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.table__cell {
    padding: 12px 16px;
}

.table__body .table__cell {
    background-color: #747C8C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E4F6;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
      <thead class="table__head">
        <tr class="table__row">
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
          <th class="table__cell table__cell_title">
            Title
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table__body">
        <tr class="table__row">
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="table__row">
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="table__row">
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="table__row">
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="table__row">
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell">
              Text
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried to set overflow for both body and header sections separately but in this case I need to make synchronized scroll because in this case they'll scroll independently. Is there some another way to set border-radius to overflowing table?

Answer (score 1):

Simple just apply overflow to the table body.

```
.table__body {
   display: grid;
   border-radius: 16px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

And you talk about scroll synchronized then there is one js plugin which will sync the both scroll at a same time (https://github.com/asvd/intence) have a look at it and hope you get solution for this!! :)

Comment: Hi!! thanks for the reply! Your solution works but it makes radiuses for endings of overflowing table but not on the borders of table. Thanks for the plugin for managing scroll but I wonder if there is a way to make what I want in pure CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Since `@patel-harsh`'s solution doesn't fit the expected result, here's a more complex CSS selector solution using `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors

```css
table tr:first-child td:first-child { border-radius: 7px 0 0 0; }
table tr:first-child td:last-child { border-radius: 0 7px 0 0; }
table tr:last-child td:first-child { border-radius: 0 0 0 7px; }
table tr:last-child td:last-child { border-radius: 0 0 7px 0; }

/* following section is for visual purposes */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    padding: 7px 12px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fourth</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fifth</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! in this case radiuses will be on the first and last elements but not on the endings of table body. What I'd like to achieve is to have radiuses even if my table is scrollable

Comment: Oh my bad, then you are asking the wrong question. I'm guessing you want the table to be scrollable yet keep the radius? in that case the table has nothing to do here, it's your container that sould set a bordered frame and inside have the table. Would you like a CSS code for that?

Comment: I just saw your example, you want a horizontal scroll + border-radius layer, which is not possible without Javascript. The process would be to set the headers (table thead) in a table, the content in another table wrapped by a bordered container (div.radius > table tbody), match the widths of headers with the contents and scroll the header when the table is scrolled.. This is not something you can do only with CSS